# Modifying the text of labels for pieces in a pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have nodes to place in a pie chart. In each case, the percentage is to be put on its own line.  I tried using `//` to do this, but it only removed the space between a word in the label and the percentage. (For the node containing "Rent and Utililities 35\%, I would like to have three lines.)

I tried using the `pin` option to place one of the nodes outside the pie chart.  That was a disaster.  I would like to get the pin at an angle of 225 degrees pointing to the upper right corner of an invisible rectangular node containing "Clothing" and "5\%" on separate lines.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (90:3);
\draw (O) -- (216:3);
\draw (O) -- (234:3);
\draw (O) -- (288:3);

\path (O) -- node{Food 25\%} (45:3);
\path (O) -- node{Rent and Utilities 35\%} (153:3);
\path (O) -- node{pin distance=1cm,pin=below left:Clothing 5\%} (225:3);
\path (O) -- node{Other 5\%} (261:3);
\path (O) -- node{Car 20\%} (324:3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you like to obtain?
[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={align=center},
     pin distance=17mm
                    ]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw (O) circle (3);
\draw (O) -- (0:3);
\draw (O) -- (90:3);
\draw (O) -- (216:3);
\draw (O) -- (234:3);
\draw (O) -- (288:3);

\path (O) -- node{Food\\ 25\%} (45:3);
\path (O) -- node{Rent and\\ Utilities\\ 35\%} (153:3);
\path (O) -- node[pin=225:Clothing\\ 5\%] {} (225:3);
\path (O) -- node{Other\\ 5\%} (261:3);
\path (O) -- node{Car\\ 20\%} (324:3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`pin` as well `label` are option of node, so it should be in brackets and not part of node content (see code above). For writing text in shape in more lines you should define `text width` or option `align=left` or `center` or `right` or `justify`. If you like to have pin with arrow, then `pin distance` replace for example with:

```
every   pin/.style  = {inner sep=1pt, align=center, 
                       pin distance = 17mm,
                       edge={<-, solid, shorten <=1mm}},
```

Comment: As the `pin distance` value is accessed outside the `node` path operator (via `append after command`) it must be set accordingly. `\path[pin distance] (O) -- node[pin=…]{} (225:3);` should work as well. (Your solution is not wrong, I just want to add some information.)

Comment: Thank you to remain me on this possibilities. I rare use it. In this case the determination of size pin distance is moved to command, in this case is  ``\path[pin distance=17mm]  ... ``

Comment: @Zarko  From the examples in the manual, I didn't see that `pin` was an option for the `node` command.  Thanks.  How do I specify alignment within each node?  (I see that you have `every node/.style={align=center}` as an option in the `TikZ` environment.)

Comment: @Zarko The position of `Clothing 5%` is fine.  I would like a shorter pin - one that is drawn about a third as far into the slice as the pin drawn with your code.

Comment: Try to enlarge  coordinate ``(225:3)`` to for example ``(225:4)`` and more if the node is not placed close to circle.